# Book or online article on analysis and tuning Linux system performance

Tags: linux, performance, books

I am looking for a good book or online article on analysis and tuning Linux system performance.

So far I've found [openSUSE 12.2 System Analysis and Tuning Guide](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/htmlsingle/openSUSE/opensuse-tuning.html) which looks promising. Any other recommendations?

Comment: There are great many articles on tuning various components.  Is there something specific you are looking to do?

Comment: @Karlson: First I am interested in analyzing performance bottlenecks. Until then I can't really say what exactly I am going to tune.

Comment: Performance bottlenecks of network? CPU? Memory? Software?  How do these bottlenecks show themselves?  Why do you think that there are system bottlenecks instead of the individual software ones?  Start at higher level first....

Comment: @Karlson: I have a number of virtual machines running on a server and would like to improve performance if possible. So I'd like to analyze what resource are utilized most and might need upgrade. I'd like to know a systematic way to analyze resource utilization, thus I'm looking for some recommendations on the relevant reading.

Answer (score 2):

Without delving into details of applications running on the system which is where normally performance tuning would start you can start looking at system performance through:

- https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/index.html
- http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/REDP4285.html
- http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/linux-performance-tuning_107.html
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/linux-performance-monitoring-intro/

This list is by no means complete and by no means likely to give you answers on what you might be doing.  Given that you are running multiple virtual machines I would first recommend analysis of applications running in those environments and whether or not virtualization is actually necessary.